# Why is the xQueueSendToBack call blocking?

Tags: c, embedded, freertos

I am learning FreeRTOS on a STM32F103C8T6 (on a Blue-Pill board).
I am trying to use queues and tasks.

```
#include <FreeRTOS.h>
#include <libopencm3/stm32/gpio.h>
#include <libopencm3/stm32/rcc.h>
#include <queue.h>
#include <task.h>

static QueueHandle_t queue;

static void
task_receive(void *args __attribute__((unused)))
{
  bool nothing;
  while (1)
  {
    if (xQueueReceive(queue, &nothing, 10) == pdPASS)
      gpio_set(GPIOC, GPIO13); // Turn off
    else
      taskYIELD(); // Yeld so that other taks can run
  }
}

static void
task_send(void *args __attribute__((unused)))
{
  bool nothing = false;
  while (1)
  {
    gpio_clear(GPIOC, GPIO13); // Turn on
    vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(100));
    xQueueSendToBack(queue, &nothing, portMAX_DELAY);
    vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000));
  }
}

int
main(void)
{
  rcc_clock_setup_in_hse_8mhz_out_72mhz();

  // Blue-Pill led
  rcc_periph_clock_enable(RCC_GPIOC);
  gpio_set_mode(
    GPIOC,
    GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_2_MHZ,
    GPIO_CNF_OUTPUT_PUSHPULL,
    GPIO13);
  gpio_set(GPIOC, GPIO13); // Turn off (polarity of the led is inversed!)

  queue = xQueueCreate(32, sizeof(bool));
  if (queue == 0)
  {
    while (1)
    {
      gpio_toggle(GPIOC, GPIO13);
      for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 80000; ++i)
        __asm__("nop");
    };
  }
  xTaskCreate(task_receive, "RECEIVE", 200, NULL, configMAX_PRIORITIES-1, NULL);
  xTaskCreate(task_send, "SEND", 200, NULL, configMAX_PRIORITIES-2, NULL);
  vTaskStartScheduler();
  while(1);
  return 0;
}
```

Expected behavior:

- `main`

  - Configures the clocks
  - Configures GPIO for Blue Pill LED
  - Turns off the led
  - Creates a queue
  - Checks the queue was correctly created: if not blink the LED fast and forever.
  - Schedule two tasks
  - Runs the scheduler
- `task_send` (loops indefinetely)

  - Turn on the LED
  - Wait 100 ms
  - Push a message in the queue (content does not matter here)
  - Wait 1 sec
- `task_receive` (loops indefinetely)

  - Check if a message is in the queue

    - Yes: turn off the led
    - No: yeld

I expect the led to be turned on for 100 ms and then turned off for 900 ms.

Real behavior: The led is always on, the execution of the program seems to be blocking at `xQueueSendToBack`.

Why is the call blocking?

---

`FreeRTOSConfig.h`

```
#define configUSE_PREEMPTION        1
#define configUSE_IDLE_HOOK     0
#define configUSE_TICK_HOOK     0
#define configCPU_CLOCK_HZ      ( ( unsigned long ) 72000000 )  
#define configSYSTICK_CLOCK_HZ      ( configCPU_CLOCK_HZ / 8 ) /* fix for vTaskDelay() */
#define configTICK_RATE_HZ      ( ( TickType_t ) 1000 )
#define configMAX_PRIORITIES        ( 5 )
#define configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE    ( ( unsigned short ) 128 )
#define configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE       ( ( size_t ) ( 17 * 1024 ) )
#define configMAX_TASK_NAME_LEN     ( 16 )
#define configUSE_TRACE_FACILITY    0
#define configUSE_16_BIT_TICKS      0
#define configIDLE_SHOULD_YIELD     1
#define configUSE_MUTEXES       1

/* Co-routine definitions. */
#define configUSE_CO_ROUTINES       0
#define configMAX_CO_ROUTINE_PRIORITIES ( 2 )

/* Set the following definitions to 1 to include the API function, or zero
to exclude the API function. */

#define INCLUDE_vTaskPrioritySet        1
#define INCLUDE_uxTaskPriorityGet       1
#define INCLUDE_vTaskDelete             1
#define INCLUDE_vTaskCleanUpResources   0
#define INCLUDE_vTaskSuspend            1
#define INCLUDE_vTaskDelayUntil         1
#define INCLUDE_vTaskDelay              1

/* This is the raw value as per the Cortex-M3 NVIC.  Values can be 255
(lowest) to 0 (1?) (highest). */
#define configKERNEL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY         255
/* !!!! configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY must not be set to zero !!!!
See http://www.FreeRTOS.org/RTOS-Cortex-M3-M4.html. */
#define configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY    191 /* equivalent to 0xb0, or priority 11. */


/* This is the value being used as per the ST library which permits 16
priority values, 0 to 15.  This must correspond to the
configKERNEL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY setting.  Here 15 corresponds to the lowest
NVIC value of 255. */
#define configLIBRARY_KERNEL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY 15
```

Comment: In your example `task_receive` priority is higher than the `task_send` priority, therefore yielding in the higher priority task would yield the calling task over again. Therefore your `send_task` won't be preempted at all. Have a look at this  https://www.freertos.org/a00020.html#taskYIELD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by updating the compiler to the latest version.

Kubuntu 18.04 ships with `arm-none-eabi-gcc (15:6.3.1+svn253039-1build1) 6.3.1 20170620`, with this compiler the code does not work.

`memcpy` seems to be the problematic function call in the code, it is called by FreeRTOS when adding an element to the queue.

If I use the `Version 8-2018-q4-major Linux 64-bit` compiler then the code executes fine. It can be downloaded here: https://developer.arm.com/open-source/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads

Answer (score 2):

Your `task_receive` priority is higher than the `task_send` priority. `taskYIELD` will run the same calling task over and over again if there are no higher priority tasks.

To achieve what you want, try changing the `task_receive` in the following manner.

```
static void
task_receive(void *args __attribute__((unused)))
{
  bool nothing;
  while (1)
  {
    if (xQueueReceive(queue, &nothing, portMAX_DELAY) == pdPASS)
      gpio_set(GPIOC, GPIO13); // Turn off
  }
}
```

For more information on taskYIELD please refer the following.

https://www.freertos.org/a00020.html#taskYIELD

Comment: I have tried this change but it does not improve the behavior of the led (it is turned on and never turns off). I have also tried to make the two tasks have the same priority: no better.

Comment: Let me make an educated guess here. Isn't your code getting stuck at `vTaskDelay` rather than in `xQueueSendToBack`. If that is the case make sure that your systick ISR(I assume systick is the RTOS tick source) is properly configured to call FreeRTOS tick function. Have a look as how `libopencm3` takes care of the systick ISR.

Comment: I think it is is correctly configured. I have created an example to blink the led with two tasks (one tasks turns the led on, the other turns the led off), each of them calls `vTaskDelay` and it works fine. https://gist.github.com/VictorLamoine/8bbb9caeaae32f0d3348ecdba060eae7

Comment: Do you have the facility to step through the source code via a debugger? It seems that you are hitting a `configAssert` in FreeRTOS code. Again, I hope that by this time you've already checked if the stack size of `200` words is sufficient for the 2 tasks.

Comment: I have tried with stack sizes 400, 800, 1400, upto 1800 words with no visible change. Yes I can debug with my ST-Link. I get stuck on a comparison call, when I hit step on the statement nothing happens. https://gist.github.com/VictorLamoine/8bbb9caeaae32f0d3348ecdba060eae7#file-queue_test-gdb. File can be read at https://github.com/cjlano/freertos/blob/master/FreeRTOS/Source/queue.c#L2100

Comment: @VictorLamoine I can't find anything wrong with the code(with the non `taskYIELD` one). I tried a similar code on a different board and seems to work completely fine(I replaced you GPIO calls with UART-printfs). May be you better try to do the same thing with STM32Cube HAL bypassing libopencm3 dependencies - just a suggestion. For further help you better use FreeRTOS discussion forum.

Comment: @VictorLamoine Further, depending upon your heap allocation strategy(heap_1,..heap_5), FreeRTOS may or may not allocate all the memory (stack & FreeRTOS heap) from the HEAP_SIZE you specifies. See if it fits within the maximum RAM available in the chip as well. May be you better muck around a bit with `HEAP_SIZE` configuration in `FreeRTOS_Config.h` file as well to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Discussion continues here: https://sourceforge.net/p/freertos/discussion/382005/thread/8127550229/. There is a problem with memcpy, not sure what yet.